# is this an Array, Object or only a String that Looks like Json and outputted from PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, json

Well I have a problem reading the JSON data in jQuery, which is outputted by PHP,
I´m alreaddy using `json_encode();`

```
<?php
require_once 'Post_db.php'; // a Class for doing MySQL work

/* the Post class */    
class Post {

/* An array that stores the post item data: */

private $pdata;

/* The constructor */
public function __construct($postData){
if(is_array($postData))
$this->pdata= $postData;
}



public function __toString(){
// The string that is beeing returned
// is outputed by the echo statement

$toBeJsoned=$this->pdata;
$toBeSent=json_encode($toBeJsoned);
return  $toBeSent;  
}

//read the Posts
public static function readPosts(){
$query = new Post_db("SELECT * FROM pmessage
                 ORDER BY p_id DESC
                 ");
$posts = array();
while($row = $query->fetchRow()){
$posts [] = new Post($row);
}
foreach($posts as $item){

echo $item;
}
}
```

Now the Jquery :

This code is reading , but this is only a `$.get` method. And it returnes `myPosts` as 1 array with a about 5000 elmenets but there are only about 50 Posts, so it is getting each charachter from this string as an array element.

```
function readMyPosts(){
        $.get("phpFileThatCalltheFunctionsToRead.php",
                      {"action": "autoRead"},
                      function(myPosts){        
            //a ul element
            $("#plist").html("<li>"+myPosts+"</li>");       

               });
                 }
    readMyFacts();
```

When I try with `$.ajax` or `$.getJSON`, I never reach the success function, actully nothing happenes

```
  function ReadNewestFacts(){
        $.ajax({
        url:"phpFileThatCalltheFunctionsToRead.php", 
        data:"action=autoRead_main",
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(json){
            //do something with the data 
            alert(json);


            }});
      }
   //run this function
        ReadNewestFacts();
```

The `phpFileThatCalltheFunctionsToRead.php` file looks like this:

```
<?php

session_start();
require_once "post.class.php";


 if(isset($thisUid)){
$thisUid= $_GET['thisUid'];
}

if(isset($action)){
$action = $_GET['action'];
}

try{
    switch($_GET['action'])
    {
        case 'autoRead_main':
            Post::readPosts();
            break;      

        case 'autoRead':
            Post::readMyPosts($_GET['thisUid']);
            break;
            case ' more cases
               ..
                  .
                .
              .'




    }

}
catch(Exception $e){
    // echo $e->getMessage();
    die("0");
}
```

All I was able to recive is

```
{"p_id":"1","p_text":"blabla","p_adder":"1"}{"p_id":"2","p_text":"blabla2","p_adder":"1"}{"p_id":"3","p_text":"more blabla","p_adder":"2"}{"p_id":"4","p_text":"more and more blabla","p_adder":"1"}{}....
```

The JSON formatting seems to be working correctly !?,, but I think the Jquery not beeing able to read the JSON String from PHP ? I´m really not sure  here  :( ..

I´m not beeing able to access the JSON data on the jQuery side.. I tried many methods found here on StacKover.. but I think im missing something ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're outputting multiple JSON objects together.

This is because each `Post` object in your PHP code outputs a single block of JSON. You're creating an array of `Post` objects, and so you're getting multiple blocks of JSON.

Each block of JSON you're generating is valid, but simply concatenating them together is not valid JSON.

If you want to have your `Post` objects output an array of their JSON objects, then you need to write the JSON code for that as well.

You can't `json_encode` the whole thing, because it's already encoded, so the easist way to fix it in your code is just to print `[` and `]` at either end of your output, and a comma between each `Post` object output.

You could do it like this:

```
echo '['.implode(',',$posts).']';
```

instead of your `foreach()` loop.

Comment: thanks ,, this is helpfull ! ,, i still have no enough reputation to vote ^^

Comment: @akkawi - glad it helped :)  don't worry, you only need 15 points to be able to vote, so you should be able to do it soon.

Comment: the Implode method did a perfect work , and if anyone would like to see how the Json code is:  here is the Success function after calling getJson  ...   


function(data){ for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  $("#htmltag").append(
"<li>" + data[i].p_id + " , " + data[i].p_value + "</li>");
    
   }
 
  }

Answer (score 3):

You are missing commas in between the "{ }"-blocks

```
[{"p_id":"1","p_text":"blabla","p_adder":"1"},{"p_id":"2","p_text":"blabla2","p_adder":"1"},{"p_id":"3","p_text":"more blabla","p_adder":"2"},{"p_id":"4","p_text":"more and more blabla","p_adder":"1"},{}]
```

Comment: I did that with the json_encode($var) method .. how can i add the commas there ?

Comment: I think you are encoding each "{ }"-block with json_encode() and then echoing them one after another. Instead you should add them to an array-variable and use json_encode($arrayVariable) on that variable. This will be what you want to output

Answer (score 1):

In reaction to @JochenJung, you need to have it like this:

`json_encode( array( array1, array2, ...) );` to have comma's inserted.

Answer (score 0):

use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: I´m alreaddy doing the json_encode() before sending the data !

Answer (score 0):

Try do do

```
error: function(json){
            console.log(json);//need to have firebug


            }});
```

1.Remove all empty spaces from all files.(Need to be clean)
2.Use json_encode('HERE CAN BE ARRAY);