# is this an MVC?

Tags: php, jquery, model-view-controller, design-patterns

this is a General Question about MVC ..

I wrote a PHP Class that send an Array with Core JsonData Strings to Jquery .. and on Jquery i´m accessing the data and add them to my views ( .append("htm stuff"+jsondata)  )

now the Jquery is calling the data from a between.php page that has a catch block with many cases, and upon the called case/function , the between page is calling a function from the php class that sends the json data ..

so i have my oop php model that send the core jsondata , a controller ( catch block), and the view ( the jquery page) .. is this kind of MVC ? or i did miss understand it ?

an example of my code was posted on a previous Question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151882/is-this-an-array-object-or-only-a-string-that-looks-like-json-and-outputted-from)

Comment: I haven't seen a single implementation like this.

Comment: Are you learning or developing? If developing, i would advise to use a framework, because 1. Its more secure 2. Its easyer & faster 3. Features 4. You don't have to think (this way or that? framework enforces you to do it the right way).  You can google around for a [php framework](http://www.google.com/search?q=php+framework).

Comment: just lerning   :)  ,, but thanks for the advice !

Comment: I totally agree with @Janis Veinbergs. More specifically, I'd google for an _MVC_ framework for php. [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com) is a popular one, and a brand new one called [Laravel](http://laravel.com) emphasizes a lightweight feel and speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the code you posted in your other post it is not a MVC implementation. Or at least it is a bad implementation.

The MVC is about seperating your presentation from your business logic. Looking at your POST class you don't seperate your business logic from your view:

```
public static function readPosts(){
    $query = new Post_db("SELECT * FROM pmessage
                          ORDER BY p_id DESC
                         ");

    $posts = array();
    while($row = $query->fetchRow()){
        $posts [] = new Post($row);
    }

    foreach($posts as $item){
        echo $item;
    }
}
```

In this function you get information from your database (business logic) and print content (view). In other words, you combine your MV in one method. So I would say: No, this is not MVC.

Comment: I agree, but I'd take it one step further and say that hitting the database is a data access responsibility worthy of its own layer tangential to the business layer. I'm a fan of the repository model which gives you a powerful ability to change persistence methods down the road.

Answer (score 1):

In simple word MVC is a pattern, but it should follow some pattern in coding i.e. separation of concern

- Model: the property class ,basically container for table data
- View:Simple HTML Pages that show data using the models.
- Controller:It send commands to the model to update the model's state
  .It also work like a router that send model to view and vice-versa.

*see the below link for reference...*

[Help Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Answer (score 0):

Anything that satisfies or follows [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern is called MVC. It's up to us to take it in this way or the other.

In my opinion, like I said if it satisfies MVC needs then call it MVC.